# How to use > and /> in Android drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Which items in drawables in Android should be closed with `>` and which ones should be closed with `/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define any tag's attribute and want to add some child tags is close with '>'   and when you want to end any tag without any child tags you should use '/>'

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners android:radius="@dimen/_5sdp" />
</shape>
```

Here `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
have child tags so it ended with '>' and tag closed as `</shape>`

and `<solid android:color="@color/white" />` haven't any child tag so it ended with '/>' and ended.

Comment: If you think that my answer for the initial problem helped you, please consider Upvote answer to make is useful to others too. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter which one you use. For reference, `/>` is self closing.

If your XML tag will contain one or more children, you can't close it with `/>`

Examples:

```
<element> # You can't end this with />
  <child>
</element>
```

Self closing, these both are same. You may choose to use any style.

```
<element></element>
<element />
```

Answer (score 0):

look this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">    <!--from here open since the parent has a child-->

<!--if parent note has a child then you should use close simbol "/>" like this -->
    <path
       android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z" /> <!--here close child-->

   </vector> <!--here close parent-->
```